# Conditionally Acting on Specific Error Using and_then in Rust

Tags: error-handling, rust, combinators

How do I know what error happened when piping `Result`s via `and_then` in Rust? For example using nested matches I could do this:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn get_num(n: u8) -> Result<u8, ParseIntError> {
   // Force a ParseIntError
   "foo ".parse()
}
fn add_one(n: u8) -> Result<u8, ParseIntError> {
    Ok(n + 1)
}
fn main() {
    match get_num(1) {
        Ok(n) => {
            match add_one(n) {
                Ok(n) => println!("adding one gives us: {}", n),
                Err(why) => println!("Error adding: {}", why)
            }
        },
        Err(why) => println!("Error getting number: {}", why),
    }
}
```

Or I can use `and_then` to pipe the result of the first function to the second and avoid a nested match:

```rust
match get_num(1).and_then(add_one) {
  Ok(n) => println!("Adding one gives us: {}", n),
  Err(why) => println!("Some error: {}.", why)
}
```

How do I conditionally and idiomatically determine the error in the second form, using `and_then`? Do I have to type check the error? Sure I can display the error like I did above, but let's say I want to preface it with something related to the kind of error it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way would be to use `map_err` to convert the initial errors to something richer you control e.g.

```rust
enum MyError {
    Parsing,
    Adding
}

get_num(1).map_err(|_| MyError::Parsing)
    .and_then(|v| add_one(v).map_err(|_| MyError::Adding)
```

sadly as you can see this requires using a lambda for the `and_then` callback: `and_then` must return the same error type as the input, so here it has to yield a `Result<_, MyError>`, wjhich is not the return type of `add_one`.

And while in other situations we could recover somewhat with `?`, here the same original error *type* is split into two different values.

Comment: I see. I suppose this is questionably more readable than nested matches.

Comment: @Aaron IMO, `and_then` is normally used when we don’t care exactly where an error occurred. Normally the error shall support pretty printing, so we can just rely on that for error reporting.